# Minimizing external JAR by removing all non-dependent classes from source code

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an Android project which requires Apache's POI external JARs (libraries used to read and manipulate MS Office files, but that's irrelevant).
Upon compilation I get an error stating that my project has over 65536 method declarations - I only have a few dozens and the rest are from the external libraries.

I only need a fraction of the functionality of POI so I downloaded the full source code and imported it into Eclipse. I have a list of classes I'd like to keep, however each one of these classes depends on other classes in the code, and I can only assume that these classes also have dependencies.

Is there a way to clean the source code so I'd keep only the classes I need **and all their dependencies** (without manually tracking each dependency, as there are a lot of them)?

P.S - I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392567/java-minimize-dependencies) but it deals with compiled JARs and I also have the source code.

Comment: Is there some reason why ProGuard won't work for you?

Comment: ProGuard is only used in release. I can't even debug my app (unless there's some way to activate ProGuard from Eclipse in debug mode I don't know about)

Comment: Weird. I'm using POI libraries in my project (poi and poi-scratchpad), without reaching the methods limit. Both jars doesn't take more than ~20000 methods. Try to calculate the methods count in your dex, and post the results.

Comment: If you feel desperate, you always can compile those jars in a separate project, dynamically load the dex file and access its API via reflection.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, Alex. However, I need the entire JAR suite as I'm reading XLSX as well so I need all the ooxml libraries, and so reflection is also out of the question.